# How to remove files that start with a certain prefix from php

Tags: php, symfony

I need to delete files that start with a prefix in a certain folder in my Symfony project. I have used the following code to delete for example the files start with `p_` (p_example.jpeg), but do not delete them:

**Php:**

```
public function exampleAction(){

    $Dir = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/../web/uploads/news/';

    $files=glob("'".$Dir."p_*.*'",GLOB_MARK);
    foreach($files as $file){
        if(is_file($file)){
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
 }
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: `glob("'"+$Dir+"p_*.*',GLOB_MARK")`. You've included `GLOB_MARK` as part of the first argument, instead of the optional second argument that it's supposed to be. Flag for closure: simple typographical error.

Comment: (not to mention `+` isn't the concatenation operator in php - you're looking for `.`)

Comment: Hello @Hpierce, I have changed what I say, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have resolved it with the following code:

**Php:**

```
public function exampleAction(){

  $Dir = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/../web/uploads/news/';

  $mask = $Dir."p_*.*";
  array_map( "unlink", glob( $mask ) );
}
```